# Binomial tree notation

Tags: binomial-tree

Can someone clarify for me the notation of the nodes in a binomial tree with more than 1 step? Is this notation correct?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's *more likely* that people are *familiar* with the below representation - [John Hull](http://www.prenhall.com/behindthebook/0132242265/pdf/Hull-Feature5_Whats_New.pdf) - of a **2-step binomial tree** that you described. However, by analogy, your representation (*although not conventional*) is fine too, as long as `S`,`u`,`d` are materialized by the index increments `[i,j]` at each node.

- `i++`  for each `upward / downward trend` (*1 increment*)
- `j++` for each `uptrend trend` (*idem*), whereas `j=0` in case of `downtrend`

[image: Hull 2-step Binomial Tree]